# How to find this limit

Tags: limits

Find the limit of:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2 \sin 1/x}{\sin x}$$

Answer: Since $x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}$, so $-x^2\leq x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}\leq x^2$, thus $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}=0$.
I am now stuck with the $\sin x$ under it, how does this affect the limit?

Comment: The equation $-x^2 \le x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} \le x^2$ isn't always true. If $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is negative, then the inequalities will flip.

Comment: @glacier: The equation is correct as written. $\left|x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}\right| \le \left|x^2\right|$, and $x^2$ is always nonnegative, so $-x^2 \le x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x} \le x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** using your prefered method, prove that
$$
\frac {\sin x}x\to 1
$$when $x\to 0$.

details:

once you get that, it remains
$$
\left|\frac{x^2\sin 1/x}{\sin x} \right|
= \left|\frac{x\sin 1/x}{\sin(x)/x}\right|
\le \frac{|x|}{1/2}
$$The last inequality becomes true when $x$ is close enough to $0$
because of the definition of th limit, with $\epsilon = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\sin x}{x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$
Now, assuming existence of $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\sin x}$ and $\lim_{x\to0}{x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ (you can show they exist), we can use the multiplication law
$$\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}=0\\
\text{And also }\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\sin x}=1$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sin x}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate. I answered it the other day. See [Solve $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{x^2\cdot\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726976/solve-lim-x-to0-fracx2-cdot-sin-frac1x-sin-x/727001#727001) .

The easiest approach is to write the expression as
$$
\dfrac{\left(\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)}
$$

and recall the behavior of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ (the numerator) and as $x\rightarrow 0$ (the denominator); these are $0$ and $1$, respectively, so the limit is $0/1=\boxed{0}$.